# How to do nested loops without causing memory leaks in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, memory-leaks

I need to do nested loops with querying lists instead of looping everything because it causes some memory leaks and crashes in flutter.
which causes a freeze that never ends.

here is an explanation :

I have those classes:

```dart
class Station {
String stationName;
}


class Line {
String lineName;
List<station> inLine;
}
```

Now I have 2 lists of  `Line`  and I need to check the for lines that have mutual stations .. here is the code I have used :

```dart
List<Station> mutualStations = [];

for (Line singleLine in listNumberOne) {
  for (Station inline in singleLine.inLine){
     for(line secondLine in listNumberTwo) {
        for(station secondInLine in secondLine.inLine){
            if (inline.name == secondInLine.name) {
                Station instanceOFStation = Station(name: inLine.name);
                mutualStations.add(instanceOFStation);
             }
        }
     }
   }
}

And for sure this code is a huge memory leak and am sure flutter have an easier way to do it .. anyone can help?
```

Comment: When you say “leak”, is there really a leak or is it just that the peak memory usage is higher than you expected? Perhaps you can share (a) the details of the crash; and (b) the details on how you diagnosed the memory “leak”.

Comment: it is simply freezing, and the only way to get rid of it is to close the application

Comment: Like Rob said, there is no infinite loop or anything here. Maybe just some heavy processing ? Put a few `print` statements at the beginning of each loop (and inside your if condition) to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Flutter, please correct me if I am wrong, but I think this code is running on the UI thread, which is also responsible for rendering the UI element. So, in case the UI thread is busy in the above code, your APP would freeze for some time.

I can't help but notice that your algorithm is of `O(n^4)`, which is very very slow. Considering the list contains 10 lines with each one containing 10 stations, the loop will iterate through 10^4 times i.e. 10,000 times.

Also, in case there are 50% matching stations, then you are creating around 5,000 objects inside the loop, since you haven't checked whether the stations are duplicate or not.

One of the optimization I could provide is create two different set of station name. And then loop over them to determine the mutual stations.

So, to create the Set you would loop with `O(n^2)` twice and then loop once over the set `O(m)` [ m -> Number of stations in the Set].

So considering worst case, we would get all station name as unique, which would be resolved as follows:

```
2 * O(n^2) + O(m) => 2 * 100 + 200 => 400 iterations
```

Which Optimise the time and memory consumption by **96%** (From 10,000 iterations to 400 iterations). Which reduces the load on UI thread and make your app responsive to the user. **Also, by avoiding that much amount of object allocation, you save your app from Memory leak.**